# Online pdf viewers to restrict users from saving files

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer

We have a few pdf files stored on the sever, the path is known and those files are accessible using a url.

Our requirement is, our customers should not be able to download, print, or save these pdf files.

Are there any services available online, which can display the pdf contents in the browser but not let the user download/print or save the file?

Expecting users to use chrome's settings to view the pdf contents is not practical.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your customers are always able to take a photograph of their screen (and they could improve some open source PDF viewer, like [evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince) to fit their needs). My feeling is that your requirements are unrealistic (since [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF) is an open standard)

Comment: yes they can take photographs, and its possible that they can take screenshots as well. Without proper IRM we wont be able to restrict these activities. However, this is a requirement we have to fulfill anyway.

Comment: You should ask why these requirements were given, and what is the problem they are trying to solve. The requirements sound like someone had a problem, but they didn't understand the tools available, so result is non-sensical.

Comment: What will happen to you if you cannot fullfil that requirement? What about users that are computer scientists living on some other continent? Did you ask a lawyer about the requirements (which might be illegal in the European Union, ask your lawyer to study the [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation))?

Comment: You can disallow Saving and Printing per PDF settings

Answer (score -1):

I was able to achieve my objective.

The comments from everyone are noted. I also agree that users of my application will be able to take screenshots, or some users will try to find out the pdf file in the browser cache.

However, there are certain requirements our clients want us to fulfill; they have their own reasons. And we have to oblige them.

In such situations, we ensure that the client understands the risks and the pitfalls.

Here is the code snippet

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .embed-cover {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          right: 0;
          
          /* Just for demonstration, remove this part */
          opacity: 0.25;
        }

        .wrapper {
          position: relative;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function disableContextMenu() {
            window.frames["pdfframe"].contentDocument.oncontextmenu = function(){return true;};   
            var myFrame = document.getElementById('pdfframe');
            myFrame.window.eval('document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {e.preventDefault();}, false)');
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="disableContextMenu();" oncontextmenu="return false">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <embed id="pdfframe" src="<url of myfile.pdf>#toolbar=0" width="100%" height="100%" ></embed>
        <div class="embed-cover"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is HTML, not PDF. Did you try to use Linux, then [GNU wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to fetch the PDF file (into some local file like `$HOME/f.pdf` on the computer, so `/usr/bin/wget http://remoteweb.com/remote-file.pdf -o $HOME/f.pdf`). Then reboot Linux, cut every Internet connection, and view the PDF file using `evince $HOME/f.pdf` ? I could bet 30€ that it works, or patch the [Dillo web browser](https://www.dillo.org/) to make that work.

Comment: Extremely simple to circumvect: use view page source with Firefox, then copy the URL.... (perhaps first with pencil and paper). Hence I downvoted your answer (which I did try locally)